# Get hashtable value by key of group object under strict mode version 2?

Tags: powershell

The following script, which pivot the array list by `x` and `y`, doesn't work. (`$hashvariable.x` not working). How to rewrite it? It seems it's not easy to simple get a value by key in a hashtable under strict mode.

```
Set-StrictMode -version 2 # change 2 to 1 will work

$a = @('a','b','x',10), 
     @('a','b','y',20), 
     @('c','e','x',50), 
     @('c','e','y',30)

$a | %{ 
    new-object PsObject -prop @{"label" = "'$($_[0])','$($_[1])'"; value=@{ $_[2]=$_[3]}} 
} | 
group label | % {
    "$($_.Name), $($_.Group.value.x), $($_.Group.value.y)" # error
    #"$($_.Name), $($_.Group.value['x']), $($_.Group.value['y'])" # empty for x,y
}
```

Expected result.

```
'a','b', 10, 20
'c','e', 50, 30
```

Error:

```
Property 'x' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At line:6 char:35
+     "[$(@($_.Name -split ",") + @($_.Group.value.x, $_.Group.value.y))]"
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

Comment: I'm on v3 and I do no have any error copy and paste your code. I cannot replicate it.

Comment: it is consequences of enabled strict mode, a version doesn't matter.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to return such string `'a','b', 10, 20`? Or you want to return array with four elements?

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes, I want to return `'a','b',10,20` eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you really want, but this is my best guess. You should accumulate all objects in one group in single `Hashtable` object instead of creating separate `Hashtable` for each input object:

```
$a = ('a','b','x',10), 
     ('a','b','y',20), 
     ('c','e','x',50), 
     ('c','e','y',30)

$a |
Group-Object {$_[0]},{$_[1]} |
Select-Object Values,
              @{
                  Name='Group'
                  Expression={
                      $_.Group |
                      ForEach-Object {$t=@{}}{$t.Add($_[2],$_[3])}{$t}
                  }
              } |
ForEach-Object {
    '''{0}'',''{1}'', {2}, {3}'-f@($_.Values;$_.Group['x','y'])
}
```

Comment: The script try to pivot the array list by `x`, `y`. I've updated the question.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 I made necessary changes in my answer.

Comment: Great solution. The last change `$_.Group['x','y']` resolved the issue of missing `x` or `y` for some groups. Does it always guarantee the order of `x, y`?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Yes, it should take values in same order, as you provide keys. So `['x','y']` will first return value for `x`, and than value for `y`.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand what, in fact, this script does, anyway, the problem is that only first element in a collection $_.Group.Value has the property 'x', at the same time, strict mode prohibits references to non-existent properties of an object, so you receive this error.

Here is a solution, hope I've understood right what you want:

```
$a = @('a','b','x',10), 
     @('a','b','y',20), 
     @('c','e','x',50), 
     @('c','e','y',30)

$hashtable = @{}

$a |%{
    $hashtable["$($_[0]) $($_[1])"] += 
        [hashtable]@{$_[2] = $_[3]}
}

$hashtable.GetEnumerator() | %{
    "$($_.Key) $($_.Value['x']) $($_.Value['y'])"   
}
```

Comment: How to implement it under strict mode?